# Get customer order count in new order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I'd like to indicate in WooCommerce "new order" email notification, if it's a repeat customer.

It seems simple, but I've tried about 5 different methods and none worked. I've tried putting this into 2 different hooks:

- **`woocommerce_email_after_order_table`**
- **`woocommerce_email_subject_new_order`**.

Seems like **`wc_get_customer_order_count($user->ID)`** should work but it appears that the **`$user`** object is not passed into those hook's functions, right?

I'm also wondering if this is possible when it's a guest and not a registered user, maybe by comparing the email address?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WooCommerce Email notifications are related to orders.**

In `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` hook, you have the Order object as an argument in your hooked custom function and also the `$email` object.

With that **`$order`** object, you can get the **`user ID`** this way:

```
$user_id = $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
```

From the **`$email`** object you can target the new order email notification.

So the working code is going to be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'customer_order_count', 10, 4);
function customer_order_count( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){

    if ( $order->get_user_id() > 0 ){

        // Targetting new orders (that will be sent to customer and to shop manager)
        if ( 'new_order' == $email->id ){

            // Getting the user ID
            $user_id = $order->get_user_id();

            // Get the user order count
            $order_count = wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id );

            // Display the user order count
            echo '<p>Customer order count: '.$order_count.'</p>';

        }
    }
}
```

You can also use instead the  **`woocommerce_email_before_order_table`** hook for example…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Wish I would've asked sooner. :-P

Comment: Interestingly no matter which email hook I use, wc_get_customer_order_count always seems to be 1 less than the actual order count, as if it does not cover the new order. Something to keep in mind...