# How to display WooCommerce customer past total order's count on new order email notifications to the admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm needing to have a customer's total completed order count displayed on the new order emails going to the admin of the store. On *"[Get customer order count in new order email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125823/get-customer-order-count-in-new-order-email-notification)"* answer, but I'm not getting back the total completed orders. I'm also wanting it to display a message to alert the admin if it's a customers first order.

I've linked the current script I'm using as an example, but it does not give accurate total past orders and I need it to gather counts by billing email address. I would like to only count completed orders also.

Comment: Here's the link to the script I'm trying to use as a base: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125823/get-customer-order-count-in-new-order-email-notification

Comment: I'm also wanting to search for past orders by the user's billing email address. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't make real changes to any stackOverFlow answer code, just add the link in your question (it's enough), not the code please. In stackOverFlow: 1) we don't *"code it for you"*, you need to do it yourself, and if you have some problems with your code you can ask for help. 2) Also the rule is to ask one question at the time, if you don't want your question to be closed as "too broad".